# Javascript, creating button click function in a loop always gets the same values from variables

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a JavaScript function to create a pop up based on some data.
The data in result is not important, and can be omitted for this purpose, but I am including it becasue of some additional questions

The idea is that I want to send a portion of the result array to each pop up when the corresponding button is clicked

I first tried it with `v_popup["dataarray"] = result.slice(counter, indices[i] + counter);`  but in the pop up the array is always empty

Next I tried to create a `var sub_array = result.slice(counter, indices[i] + counter);` but this was always empty

Last attempt I just sent the entire array to pop-up and added low and high limit as variables. But again, the limits are always 93 and 94 in every instance of the pop up.

If I breakpoint on `var high = indices[i] + counter;` I can see the `low` and `high` variables are storing correct incremental limits each time, but for some reason if I breakpoint inside the onlick function, on `v_popup["high"] = high;` the `low` and `high` are always 93 and 94

Is it because there is only one function that gets created for all of the buttons,

Does this function not get created until I click on the button? Does it not get created while the for loop is running?

Also, do I need a different variable for each instance of the button, such as `v_popup["dataarray1"]`, `v_popup["dataarray2"]`,...etc

Next, how can I just copy a sliced array into the variable, so I don't need to set the limits

Final question, this works when I close the pop up between clicking on each button, but if the pop-up is left open, the `window["dataarray"]` variable becomes undefined, even though `v_popup["dataarray"] = result` is executed on every button click. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
function addTable(result, indices) {
    counter = 0;
    indices = [2,3,6,2,4,4,1,5,3,1,1,1,2,4,12,1,4,4,2,1,4,1,12,13,1,]; //for testing
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerHTML = result[counter][0];
        btn.className = "button-28";
        var low = counter;
        var high = indices[i] + counter;
        btn.onclick = function () {

            var v_popup = window.open("popup.html", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=700,left=50,top=50,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no')
            v_popup["dataarray"] = result;
            v_popup["low"] = low;
            v_popup["high"] = high;
            var sub_array = result.slice(counter, indices[i] + counter); //for test
        }
        counter += indices[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a copy of said variables to pass to the event handler. This is done using a function call. It's called an IIFE. Maybe you only need some of the parameters and not all of `result, low, high, counter, i`

```js
function addTable(result, indices) {
  counter = 0;
  indices = [2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 12, 1, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 12, 13, 1, ]; //for testing
  for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = result[counter][0];
    btn.className = "button-28";
    var low = counter;
    var high = indices[i] + counter;

   
    (function(result, low, high, counter, i) {

      btn.onclick = function() {

        var v_popup = window.open("popup.html", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=700,left=50,top=50,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no')
        v_popup["dataarray"] = result;
        v_popup["low"] = low;
        v_popup["high"] = high;
        var sub_array = result.slice(counter, indices[i] + counter); //for test
      }


    })(result, low, high, counter, i);

    counter += indices[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: THis is much simpler and it works, but I dont understand the syntax , why is `(result, low, high, counter, i)` at the beginning and at the end,

Comment: it's a definition of a function, and the call to that function. all in "one line". like `(function(x){console.log(x)})(12)`

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, but I'm not sure its the best way

```
function addTable(result, indices) {
    counter = 0;
    low = [];
    high = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerHTML = result[counter][0];
        btn.className = "button-28";
        low[result[counter][0]] = counter;
        high[result[counter][0]] = indices[i] + counter;

        btn.onclick = function () {

            var v_popup = window.open("popup.html", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=700,left=50,top=50,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no')
            var indx = i;
            v_popup["dataarray"] = result.slice(low[this.innerHTML], high[this.innerHTML]);

        }
        counter += indices[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code in an edit.

Comment: I can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function addTable(result, indices) {
counter = 0;
low = [];
high = [];
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {

    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = result[counter][0];
    btn.className = "button-28";
    var low = counter;
    var high = indices[i] + counter;
    var sub_array = result.slice(low, high);

    (function (sub_array) {
        btn.onclick = function () {

            var v_popup = window.open("popup.html", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=700,left=50,top=50,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=no')
            v_popup["dataarray"] = sub_array;
        }
    })(sub_array);

    counter += indices[i];
    td.appendChild(btn);
    tr.appendChild(td);
}
```

}